# Keras Functional API: Passing In Variable Length Lists Into Embedding Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, embedding

I am presently using Keras' functional API to build a neural net that takes a mixture of numerical and categorical features. The quirk here is that every training sample may have multiple instances of a categorical variable present.

Therefore, a sample of the dataframe may look like this:

```
        sessions_sum      sessions_duration      cat_var_list     score
0          -0.554354                    100            [0, 1]       1.0
1          -0.553925                    200         [0, 2, 4]       1.0
2          -0.548787                    100            [3, 4]       0.0
3          -0.554354                    100               [5]       0.0
4          -0.553069                    100            [2, 5]       1.0
```

The `cat_var_list` column contains the a list of label-encoded categorical variables present for this training sample. I would like to create an embedding layer that takes the list of categorical indices, embeds them individually, and averages the embeddings before being concatenated with a Dense layer.

Here is the work-in-progress code that converts the data into numpy arrays and feeds them into the model.

```
# Prep data
x_train_numerics = modelDf[['sessions_sum', 'sessions_duration']].values
x_train_cats = modelDf['cat_var_list'].values
y_train = model['score'].values

# Begin model constructio 
numerics = keras.layers.Input(shape=[input_size])
layer_1 = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='layer1')(numerics)

cat_list = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), name = "subjectgroup_indices", dtype='int32')
embeddings = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=4, output_dim=10, input_length=None)(cat_list)
embeddings_avg = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: keras.backend.mean(x, axis=1))(embeddings)

hybrid_layer = keras.layers.Concatenate()([layer_1, embeddings_avg])
output_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform',
                                  name='output_layer')(hybrid_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[numerics, cat_list], outputs=output_layer)
model.compile('adam', 'mean_absolute_error')
model.fit([x_train_numerics, x_train_cats], y_train, epochs=6, batch_size=200, validation_split=0.2)
```

Which gives me the following error when I run the fit method:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-63-377ace5b4cf7>", line 1, in <module>
    model.fit([x_train_numerics, x_train_sgs], y_train, epochs=6, batch_size=200, validation_split=0.2)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3277, in __call__
    dtype=tensor_type.as_numpy_dtype))
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommendations/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I have tried setting the input shape of categorical list to `None` as suggested by the first answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45460227/keras-embedding-layer-with-variable-length-in-functional-api) question, but to no avail. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to come up with a solution for this? Would be very interested if you did

Comment: facing similar issue. pls let me know if you were able to find solution to this problem.